# Run Vertx httpServer SSL groovy

Tags: groovy, vert.x

I´m trying to create an HttpServer working on SSL with Groovy, but I´m not able to make it works, and I cannot find a good code example or documentation about it.

Here the code base that I did so far

```
    Map options = new HashMap()
    options.put("tcpKeepAlive",true)
    options.put("verifyHost", true)
    options.put("trustAll", false)
    options.put("keyCertOptions", new JksOptions().setPath("keystore.jks").setPassword("CosPassword123"))
    options.put("ssl", true)
    vertx.createHttpServer(options).requestHandler(router.&accept).listen(9000, { response ->
if (response.succeeded()) {
    startFuture.complete()
} else {
    startFuture.fail(response.cause())
}
    })
```

When When I run it I receive the exception

```
       io.vertx.core.VertxException: io.vertx.core.VertxException: Key/certificate is mandatory for SSL
at io.vertx.core.net.impl.SSLHelper.createContext(SSLHelper.java:303)
at io.vertx.core.net.impl.SSLHelper.getContext(SSLHelper.java:458)
at io.vertx.core.net.impl.SSLHelper.validate(SSLHelper.java:472)
at io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpServerImpl.listen(HttpServerImpl.java:219)
at io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpServerImpl.listen(HttpServerImpl.java:191)
at io.vertx.groovy.core.http.HttpServer.listen(HttpServer.groovy:178)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrap.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:190)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:71)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
at com.tesco.price.mocks.identity.IdentityMock.startServer(IdentityMock.groovy:67)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:210)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:59)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:174)
at com.tesco.price.mocks.identity.IdentityMock.start(IdentityMock.groovy:29)
at io.vertx.lang.groovy.GroovyVerticle$1.start(GroovyVerticle.groovy:93)
at io.vertx.core.impl.DeploymentManager.lambda$doDeploy$8(DeploymentManager.java:434)
at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$wrapTask$3(ContextImpl.java:359)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:339)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:393)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:742)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0):

"keyCertOptions" is a Java key.
In Groovy you should use "keyStoreOptions":

```
def options = [
        ssl:true,
        keyStoreOptions:[
                path:"keystore.jks",
                password:"CosPassword123"
        ]
]
vertx.createHttpServer(options).requestHandler(router.&accept).listen(9000, { response ->
    if (response.succeeded()) {
        //startFuture.complete()
    } else {
        //startFuture.fail(response.cause())
    }
})
```

Please see this for more info:
http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/groovy/#ssl

Comment: I have a working httpd ssl configuration: 1. SSLCertificateFile certificate.cer, 2. SSLCertificateKeyFile privatekey.key 3. SSLCertificateChainFile intermediate.cer. I need to create a java keystore (.jks) for vertx 3. All my attempts lead to error in the browser: www.mydomain.de uses an invalid security certificate. The certificate is not trusted because the issuer certificate is unknown. The server might not be sending the appropriate intermediate certificates. An additional root certificate may need to be imported. Error code: SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER. Can you please explain migration steps